# Click Button To Load More Products using Nuxt + Sanity.io

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, sanity

I have a list of Products in Sanity and I can successfully retrieve and display them when the page loads for the first time.

As a test, I want to add a button to add 1 more product to my list each time it is clicked, and this is the code I've written to accomplish that.

```html
<template>
  <section id="body">
    <p class="top-label font-mono text-center">
      {{ products.length }} products available
    </p>
    <div class="product-grid container mx-auto mt-8 px-4">
      <masonry :cols="{ default: 3, 700: 2 }" :gutter="20">
        <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
          <product-card
            :price="product.price"
            :url="product.url"
            :imageUrl="$urlFor(product.image).width(700).url()"
            :title="product.title"
            :description="product.description"
            :tags="product.tags"
          />
        </div>
      </masonry>
    </div>
    <button @click="addProducts">ADD PRODUCTS</button>
  </section>
</template>
```

```html
<script setup>
let end = ref(1);
let query = groq`*[_type == "product"]|order(orderRank) [0..${end.value}]`;
let { data: products, refresh } = useSanityQuery(query);

function addProducts() {
  end.value++;
  console.log("refreshing query:" + query);
  refresh();
}
</script>
```

The issue I'm running into is that the content of `query` is not changing even when `addProducts()` is called. The `console.log` outputs `refreshing query:*[_type == "product"]|order(orderRank) [0..1]` every time.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Is your state properly updating (Vue devtools)? Do you see something in your network tab?

Comment: @kissu thanks for the comment. I see the queries going through in the Network tab, but the query is the same [0..1] every time.

Comment: Go and download the Vue devtools. Then click on your component and inspect the state of your `end` variable. As for the network, open your browser devtools with the network tab and see if you have any XHR query or any error. If you're not sure what those 2 things are. Take the time to Google for them and see how it works by inspecting carefully. Have fun!

Comment: @kissu it took me a bit to get DevTools working, but it's there now. I can see that ```end``` is incrementing as it should, but the network requests show that the actual query isn't changing.

Comment: Alright, nice! Where do you call `addProducts`? I guess that here, `query` is not reactive.

Comment: @kissu I added the code for my template in the question. It's being called by a ```@click``` on a button

Comment: Try to create a `computed` or maybe a `ref` with your groq query, not sure exactly how it behaves. But it's probably not reactive in your case.

Comment: @kissu I tried so many things at this point that my brain is fried. I asked a similar question on the Nuxt/Sanity module on GitHub so hopefully someone can point out the simple error I'm making. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Do you have a public github repo?